How make Pentaho Report Designer duplicate the layout for multi select input?
I have a use case where the user will enter multiple billing numbers and expect a PDF that contains corresponding billing document for each of those numbers.
The current version I have built only accepts a single billing number and returns a single billing document.
How do I make it work for multiple billing numbers? I want Pentaho to generate a PDF with all the billing documents that are given as input using the single template that I have built.
Appreciate your help very much!
